# Pantalla negra al generar un activity nuevo en android

Tags: android, activity

[![Tengo problemas al crear un nuevo activity en android, no ingreso ningun codigo ni nada simplemente creo una nueva actividad y la pantalla se pone en color negro.
La cuestion es que al generar el apk no da problemas pero despues de instalarlo cuando llamo a esa actividad me sale un mensaje diciendo que dejo de funcionar. CLIC AQUI PARA VER LA IMAGEN DE ERROR... ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVGTf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVGTf.png)

Comment: Lo que probablemente quieres hacer es depurar la aplicación y revisar la excepción que sale cuando la aplicación deja de funcionar. Luego puedes compartir el código que haz hecho más la excepción y así puedes recibir ayuda

Comment: Revisa cual estilo tienes definido en styles.xml